# Burninate the [tree] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Burninate [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree). Not many experts, searching for the tags isn't better than searching title/body.

Also, X(HT)ML is a tree system, so... what to do? There may be questions actually about trees, but there are bunch more questions that are related too trees which may confuse people leading to mistagging.

Maybe some can be tagged [data-structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structures).

[image: A tree]

Comment: Humm, 6k questions with "tree".

Comment: @gunr2171 we are very "green" ;)

Comment: @Braiam, then this question is not "green", because it wants to burn all the trees! Ok, back to topic now.

Comment: What do these tags have in common?

Comment: @Shog9 Nothing. Do they have to be? Should I split it into separate posts?

Comment: If you're looking for folks to actually think about what you're proposing, then yes. If you just want an unthinking lynch mob, then by all means just toss random, unrelated things to be lynched in one bin and let the blood flow.

Comment: @Shog9 Thats it. I'm making a chat room entitled `The Lynch Bin`

Answer (score 10):

I don't think [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree) should be burninated.

However, in my opinion, there is not so much value in identifying specific data structures but a lot of value in identifying general data-structure related questions. For example, while I can certainly imagine somebody who is specifically an expert on trees, this strikes me as rare in comparison to somebody having knowledge of various data structures in general.

So while this doesn't address the original post specifically, I am wondering if it makes sense to make *all* specific data structure tags be a synonym for [data-structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structures).

[In a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268170/burninate-the-tree-tag/268181#comment74953_268175), *Deduplicator* noted:

> [Synonymizing these to "data-structures" is] about as reasonable as synonymizing every tag to "question".

Personally, I am of the opinion that "data-structures", while broad, is narrow *enough* to represent these questions accurately and attract the right people to the questions.

In other words, I do not necessarily see value to tagging, say, [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree) or [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) specifically and feel that [data-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structure) covers the bases for those questions well.

Answer (score 7):

A tree is a pretty well-defined concept. Assuming we're talking about the data-structure, that is. There does seem to be a fairly significant mix of questions about *tree controls* mixed into this though - from the look of it, these should be retagged [jtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtree) or the like.

I don't see how [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree) *itself* is an issue though. There are certainly data-structure experts floating around.

Comment: Are there really people who are experts in *trees*, not just data structures or something broader?

Comment: @bjb568, there must be 204 experts, or at least people who follow the tag.

Comment: @gunr2171 Meh, people follow everything.

Comment: Is it reasonable to make all specific data structure tags a synonym for [tag:data-structures]?

Comment: @JasonC: About as reasonable as synonymizing every tag to "question".

Comment: @JasonC Maybe retagging, but not synonymizing. data-structures has experts and is clearer what should be tagged as it.

Comment: Why don't you do a bit of research on that question before assuming the answer is "no", @bjb568.

Comment: There's all kinds of people with uncommon expertise, but if it's uncommon enough it's *close enough* to them not existing.

Comment: SO is useful *because* of uncommon expertise, @bjb568. That's not hyperbole - massive numbers of people come here because of answers to incredibly obscure questions on fairly obscure topics. Helping folks find this stuff rather than burying it is sorta *what we do here*...

Comment: Huh. Good point, tho tag misuse is still a problem.

Comment: @bjb568 Trees are a richer subject than I think you realize.  When you start to need true performance out of them, the differences between various types of trees and balancing algorithms are pretty nuanced.  More than tag worthy.

Comment: "I am the Lorax. I speak for the trees. I speak for the trees for the trees have no tongues." - Dr. Suess

Answer (score 0):

> **Not many** experts...

But there are experts. Which means that this isn't a Meta tag.

It also uniquely identifies a programming topic. A tree is a specific kind of programming data structure.

that being said, "not many experts" isn't a legitimate reason to burninate at all. This tag is just fine "as is."